# Passing state from parent component to child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-state

I am a bit lost when it comes to passing a state from a component to a function. I have successfully passed a state from Home into ListHome(A component being imported and rendered into Home) but I am struggling to continue passing it to a function that is being rendered in ListHome(Slider). Mainly due to it being a function.

I have looked over the docs again but am still struggling to understand how this should work. A direct edit/example would be super helpful!

I am rendering Home in a stack in App.js. If you wish for me to include this file just let me know.

I appreciate any insight at all more than you know.

Home.js

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      visible: true,
      whichComponentToShow: 'Screen1'
    };
}

goToMap = () => {
  this.setState({whichComponentToShow: 'Screen2'})
}
goToList = () => {
  this.setState({whichComponentToShow: 'Screen1'})
}

  render(){
     if(this.state.whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1'){
      return(
       <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
        <ListHome
          renderMap = {this.goToMap.bind(this)}
          renderList = {this.goToList.bind(this)}
        />
```

ListHome.js

```
export default class ListHome extends React.Component {
  
  goToMap = () => {
    this.props.renderMap();
  }

  goToList = () => {
    this.props.renderList();
  }

render() {
  return (

     <Slider
         renderMap = {this.goToMap.bind(this)}
         renderList = {this.goToList.bind(this)}
     />
```

Slider.js(I have not implemented anything into this file in attempt to pass the state yet)

```
const Slider = (props) => {
  
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  let transformX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  //animation code I removed that uses the above const and let


  return (
    //code I removed that just creates a button. 
    //The touchable opacity is how I want to use the state.
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.goToMap}>

    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}


export default Slider
```

Comment: I'd recommend to prepare a minimal code example which is easy to overview and shows your actual problem only. This should not contain  usecase-specific elements which are unrelated to the question.

Comment: const Slider = (props) => { ... }    then you can access the props like props. renderList

Comment: Also, is there any reason why you are using class components?

Comment: Could you elaborate @sojin ?

Comment: Its just how I started the project. Should I use functions over class components? @ImanpalSingh

Comment: using the latest React version you can use functional components, no need to use class components. and for functional components values passing from the parent is to child function is coming as an argument so, you can use the argument in functional component, just modify the slider component as I was given and use props.parentValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state and state-setting callbacks are defined as class methods in the `Home` class component. You can access them with `this.goToMap` and `this.goToList` and pass them into `ListHome` as component props.

In the `ListHome` class component you can access each with `this.props.renderMap` and `this.props.renderList` because that is what the props are named.

In the `Slider` function component you can access each with `props.renderMap` and `props.renderList` because that is what the props are named (note the lack of `this` to access props in a function component).

This is commonly referred to as prop-drilling. You are just passing *a reference* to the original function all the way down from `App` -> `ListHome` -> `Slider` so that it can eventually be executed.

There is no need to re-define this function on the way down. All you are saying is that when there is an `onPress/onClick` event, execute the function. And the function you want to execute is the one defined in `Home`.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      whichComponentToShow: "Screen1"
    };
  }

  goToMap = () => {
    this.setState({ whichComponentToShow: "Screen2" });
  };
  goToList = () => {
    this.setState({ whichComponentToShow: "Screen1" });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.whichComponentToShow === "Screen1") {
      return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#eee", flex: 1 }}>
          <h1>home - screen 1</h1>
          state:
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
          <ListHome renderMap={this.goToMap} renderList={this.goToList} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "pink", flex: 1 }}>
          <h1>home - screen 2</h1>
          state:
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
          <ListHome renderMap={this.goToMap} renderList={this.goToList} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

class ListHome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#ddd", flex: 1 }}>
        <h2>ListHome</h2>
        ListHome
        <Slider
          renderMap={this.props.renderMap}
          renderList={this.props.renderList}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Slider = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", flex: 1 }}>
      <h3>Slider</h3>
      <button onClick={props.renderMap}>Map</button>
      <button onClick={props.renderList}>List</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit friendly-pine-3j7x2]

Comment: I am trying to call the renderMap from slider in my project but it does not seem to work unfortunately. I updated my code to what it is now. I am getting 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.'

Comment: I appreciate your help and the example! I might start from scratch and build up after I get it working. Is there any chance I could send you more of the code in those files individually so you could help specifically to my project?

Comment: That sounds like work. Why not just ask a question here on stackoverflow when you get stuck?

Comment: My first comment was my question, I included the error I am receiving after implementing it the way you showed me

Comment: If I were you I would create a new question, with the code you have written and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can drill the props to the component, I have rewritten the code with functional components. It is not tested.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const [componentToShow, setComponentToShow] = useState('Screen1');

  const goToMap = () => {
  setComponentToShow('Screen2')
}
 const goToList = () => {
  setComponentToShow('Screen1')
}

  return(
     { (whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1') ? (
       <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
        <ListHome
          renderMap = {goToMap}
          renderList = {goToList}
        />)
:<></>
     })
```

```
export default function ListHome({renderMap, renderList}) {
  
  return (

     <Slider
         renderMap= {renderMap}
         renderList = {renderList}
     />
)
```

```
const Slider = ({renderMap, renderList}) => { // you have them here
  
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  let transformX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  //animation code I removed that uses the above const and let


  return (
    //code I removed that just creates a button. 
    //The touchable opacity is how I want to use the state.
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={renderMap}>

    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```